# how to display image on success notification message in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

How to display image of product in success message of OpenCart when user click on add to cart button?
I changed in  `catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php`  this code:

```
$json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['name'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
```

to this

```
$json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'), $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->post['product_id']), $product_info['image'], $this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
```

but result was something like this:

> You added  data/demo/hp_1.jpg to your cart.

Comment: Try using `<img>` tags.

Comment: where should I use this tag?

Comment: Around the URL for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to post the answer here, which I had previously commented.
In the reply, put the image URL into an `<img>` tag. That's all there is to it.